# Matplotlib: Plot columns of pandas dataframe with different marker and label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have pandas dataframe named red_all that looks like this:

```
      a*         b*  
s1    32.649998 9.950000
s2    45.359997 18.160000
s3    50.539997 23.759998
s4    54.269997 33.019997
s5    44.219997 29.029999
s6    32.349998 20.830000
s7    17.320000 12.360000
```

I would like to plot b* (y-axis) vs a* (x-axis) with each of the point having a different marker and different label.
So far I have tried this:

```
s = ['o','v','<','>','p','s','8']
dis_red = ['6.3%r/94.7%w','25%r/75%w','50%r/50%w','red','98.5%r/1.5%b','94.1r/5.9%b','80%r/20%b']

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(red_all['a*'], red_all['b*'], 'r', marker=s, label=dis_red)
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-60, 60, -60, 85])
plt.xlabel('Chromaticity a*',fontsize=16, fontweight = 'bold')
plt.ylabel('Chromaticity b*', fontsize=16, fontweight = 'bold')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

When I try to run it I get:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['o', 'v', '<', '>', 'p', 's', '8']
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a scatter plot:

```
vx = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
vy = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

s = ['o','v','<','>','p','s','8']
l = ['label%s' % i for i in range(7)]

for x, y, marker, label in zip(vx, vy, s, l):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', marker=marker)
    plt.annotate(label, (x, y))
```

[image]

Comment: @diegus: you can use `annotate`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @diegus: you can read the [`annotate` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate). You could play with the `xytext` parameter in order to move the annotation a bit. ;-)

Comment: It is too bad that pandas cannot handle lists of markers.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing what I wanted:

```
figure1_red = zip(red_all['a*'].values,red_all['b*'].values,s,dis_red)
plt.figure(1)
for i in range(0,len(red_all['a*'])):
    plt.plot(figure1_red[i][0],figure1_red[i][1],'r',marker=figure1_red[i][2],label=figure1_red[i][3])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Chromaticity a*',fontsize=16, fontweight = 'bold')
plt.ylabel('Chromaticity b*', fontsize=16, fontweight = 'bold')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]